# Define Values to label using javascript on blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I am trying to use the label to display values in a list.

For example: apple, 500kg, $3000 using these label I will display in a list.

**to retrieve labels in javascript I used:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
function listEE(json) {       
var  ListTagEE= "";


for (var k = 0; k < json.feed.category.length; k++)       
{     
ListTagEE +=  ""+json.feed.category[k].term+"";   }


var listing = ""       
+ListTagEE+       
"" ;    
document.write(listing); 

}   

</script>


<!-- ######### Invoking the Callback Function ############# -->      
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://someadresss.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEE'>       
</script>
```

And this is code I used to replace labels with my specific values.

```
<script>
function lebel23_logo(etiqueta23) {
ratstok = new Array();
ratstok[1] = "Apple Peter"
ratstok[2] = "Mango"
ratstok[3] = "Pine Apple"



if (etiqueta23 == "Apple") {document.write(ratstok[1]);}
if (etiqueta23 == "Mango") {document.write(ratstok[2]);}
if (etiqueta23 == "Pineapp") {document.write(ratstok[3]);}

}</script>
```

earlier I was using blogger < b: loop> label tag to retrieve label. and used following code.. to display the output

```
lebel23_logo(&quot;<data:label.name/>&quot;);
```

Now I am retrieving labels in javascript through above code which is working. but not able to change label and display it with above function lebel23_logo.

Uncaught TypeError: lebel23_logo is not a function on line 9
https://js.do/helloaaa/asasqqq

sorry, my English and javascript is not that good. i hope I made this post understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `""+json.feed.category[k].term+""` with `+lebel23_logo(json.feed.category[k].term)+`

https://js.do/MustaphaBouh/asasqqq

Comment: because you have overwritten the function `lebel23_logo`, check https://js.do/MustaphaBouh/asasqqq

Comment: but here labels which are not defined gives undefined, can we hide these "undefined" which are not defined? & thank you for correcting me on above code.

Comment: new code is showing all the available labels, https://js.do/helloaaa/asasqqq , if Pineapple2 label is not used in some feeds, then it should not show. previous code is fine in that case. Need to avoid seeing undefined values.